# Where did the C# badge go on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, badges, up-votes

I used to remember seeing badges for specific categories (like the [C# badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/40/c)) for getting lots of upvotes in that category. Now these no longer show when you click on the badges tab. Does that mean you can't get this badges anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to "Badges" and click on the "Tags" tab on the far right.

(I see [TheTXI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22164/thetxi) has gained the [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/42/discussion) silver badge on Meta already :)

Comment: TheTXI wins at discussion. Way to go, TXI!