# Badges Doubly Awarded On Migration

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

In looking at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9644) question, I noticed that the affable Jon Skeet had gotten a gold badge here at Meta sometime in the last day (since he didn't have it yesterday). I looked in [his profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656), and it was a Great Answer badge for his [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts/9182#9182) answer (well deserved, btw--hilarious thread). However, he still has five Great Answer badges [at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), but only four answers that actually qualify anymore.

Should badges be doubly awarded upon migration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is intentional. The reason is that badges, especially those awarded for migrated answers, will result in a net loss of a badge on StackOverflow, so [Jeff has configured](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges) the migration system to migrate votes (and the badges).

Strictly speaking, you won't ever *lose* a badge on StackOverflow, but I consider it a *net loss* because you won't earn your *next* badge of that type. So if you had a gold badge for a 100+ score answer on SO, you'd still retain it (and gain it here once its migrated) but you wouldn't earn another badge for the *next* 100+ point answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thank yas. Didn't realize the part about foregoing your next badge.